# GlusterFS is failing to mount on boot

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, glusterfs

I'm running the official GlusterFS 3.5 packages on an Ubuntu 12.04 box that is acting as both, client and server, and everything seems to be working fine, except mounting the GlusterFS volumes at boot time. This is what I see in the log files:

```
[2014-06-17 08:20:52.969258] I [glusterfsd.c:1959:main] 0-/usr/sbin/glusterfs: Started running /usr/sbin/glusterfs version 3.5.0 (/usr/sbin/glusterfs --volfile-server=127.0.0.1 --volfile-id=/public_uploads /var/www/shared/public/uploads)
[2014-06-17 08:20:52.998985] I [socket.c:3561:socket_init] 0-glusterfs: SSL support is NOT enabled
[2014-06-17 08:20:52.999048] I [socket.c:3576:socket_init] 0-glusterfs: using system polling thread
[2014-06-17 08:20:53.000373] E [socket.c:2161:socket_connect_finish] 0-glusterfs: connection to 127.0.0.1:24007 failed (Connection refused)
[2014-06-17 08:20:53.000427] E [glusterfsd-mgmt.c:1601:mgmt_rpc_notify] 0-glusterfsd-mgmt: failed to connect with remote-host: 127.0.0.1 (No data available)
[2014-06-17 08:20:53.000442] I [glusterfsd-mgmt.c:1607:mgmt_rpc_notify] 0-glusterfsd-mgmt: Exhausted all volfile servers
[2014-06-17 08:20:53.013793] W [glusterfsd.c:1095:cleanup_and_exit] (-->/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfrpc.so.0(rpc_transport_notify+0x27) [0x7f686e0160f7] (-->/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfrpc.so.0(rpc_clnt_notify+0x1a4) [0x7f686e019cc4] (-->/usr/sbin/glusterfs(+0xcada) [0x7f686e6ddada]))) 0-: received signum (1), shutting down
[2014-06-17 08:20:53.013830] I [fuse-bridge.c:5444:fini] 0-fuse: Unmounting '/var/www/shared/public/uploads'.
```

My fstab contains:

```
proc        /proc                        proc    defaults                       0       0
/dev/xvda   /                            ext4    noatime,errors=remount-ro      0       1
/dev/xvdb   none                         swap    sw                             0       0
/dev/xvdc   /var/lib/glusterfs/brick01   ext4    defaults                       1       2
127.0.0.1:/private_uploads /var/www/shared/private/uploads glusterfs defaults,_netdev 0 0
```

I know this used to be a bug in GlusterFS 3.2 for Ubuntu, but I understand it was solved in the PPA packages for GlusterFS 3.4 as shown here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glusterfs/+bug/876648

I also remember this working in an experiment I run with some virtual machines (but since it just working, I didn't look too deep into it). I see that the gluster-client packages provides an upstart job called mounting-glusterfs.conf which contains:

```
author "Louis Zuckerman <me@louiszuckerman.com>"
description "Block the mounting event for glusterfs filesystems until the network interfaces are running"

instance $MOUNTPOINT

start on mounting TYPE=glusterfs
task
exec start wait-for-state WAIT_FOR=static-network-up WAITER=mounting-glusterfs-$MOUNTPOINT
```

But I'm not so sure how it should work. It doesn't seem to be working out of the box. Even though mounting of glusterfs volumes happens after the network starts, it happens before GlusterFS starts:

```
 * Starting RPC portmapper replacement                                   [ OK ]
 * Stopping rpcsec_gss daemon                                            [ OK ]
 * Starting Start this job to wait until rpcbind is started or fails to s[ OK ]
 * Starting configure network device                                     [ OK ]
 * Stopping Start this job to wait until rpcbind is started or fails to s[ OK ]
 * Starting Bridge socket events into upstart                            [ OK ]
 * Starting NSM status monitor                                           [ OK ]
 * Stopping cold plug devices                                            [ OK ]
 * Stopping log initial device creation                                  [ OK ]
 * Starting load fallback graphics devices                               [ OK ]
 * Starting configure network device security                            [ OK ]
 * Starting load fallback graphics devices                               [fail]
 * Starting configure virtual network devices                            [ OK ]
 * Starting Send an event to indicate plymouth is up                     [ OK ]
 * Stopping Send an event to indicate plymouth is up                     [ OK ]
 * Starting Mount network filesystems                                    [ OK ]
 * Stopping configure virtual network devices                            [ OK ]
 * Stopping Mount network filesystems                                    [ OK ]
 * Starting Mount network filesystems                                    [ OK ]
 * Stopping Mount network filesystems                                    [ OK ]
 * Starting configure network device                                     [ OK ]
 * Starting set sysctls from /etc/sysctl.conf                            [ OK ]
 * Stopping set sysctls from /etc/sysctl.conf                            [ OK ]
The disk drive for /var/www/shared/public/uploads is not ready yet or not present.
Continue to wait, or Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery
 * Starting Waiting for state                                            [fail]
 * Starting Block the mounting event for glusterfs filesystems until the [fail]k interfaces are running
mountall: Event failed


Mount failed. Please check the log file for more details.
 * Starting GNU Screen Cleanup                                           [ OK ]
 * Starting flush early job output to logs                               [ OK ]
 * Starting base                                                         [ OK ]
 * Starting save udev log and update rules                               [ OK ]
 * Starting OpenSSH server                                               [ OK ]
 * Stopping Failsafe Boot Delay                                          [ OK ]
 * Starting System V initialisation compatibility                        [ OK ]
 * Stopping save udev log and update rules                               [ OK ]
 * Stopping Mount filesystems on boot                                    [ OK ]
 * Stopping GNU Screen Cleanup                                           [ OK ]
 * Stopping flush early job output to logs                               [ OK ]
 * Starting system logging daemon                                        [ OK ]
 * Stopping System V initialisation compatibility                        [ OK ]
 * Starting System V runlevel compatibility                              [ OK ]
 * Starting save kernel messages                                         [ OK ]
 * Starting deferred execution scheduler                                 [ OK ]
 * Starting CPU interrupts balancing daemon                              [ OK ]
 * Starting regular background program processing daemon                 [ OK ]
 * Starting automatic crash report generation                            [ OK ]
 * Starting GlusterFS Management Daemon                                  [ OK ]
```

Any ideas what's going on and/or how to fix it?

As an alternative that I'm not too thrill about, I tried having an upstart job mounting those volumes. I added noauto to my fstab glusterfs entries so that they wouldn't be automatically mounted at boot item and created an upstart job with these content:

```
description "Mount public uploads"

start on started glusterfs-server

exec mount /var/www/shared/public/uploads
```

When I rebooted the server, the volume wasn't mounted. /var/log/upstart/mount_public_uploads.log contains:

```
Mount failed. Please check the log file for more details.
```

and /var/log/glusterf/var-www-shared-public-uploads.log cotains:

```
2014-06-19 15:01:47.170299] I [glusterfsd.c:1959:main] 0-/usr/sbin/glusterfs: Started running /usr/sbin/glusterfs version 3.5.0 (/usr/sbin/glusterfs --volfile-server=127.0.0.1 --volfile-id=/public_uploads /var/www/shared/public/uploads)
[2014-06-19 15:01:47.190852] I [socket.c:3561:socket_init] 0-glusterfs: SSL support is NOT enabled
[2014-06-19 15:01:47.190933] I [socket.c:3576:socket_init] 0-glusterfs: using system polling thread
[2014-06-19 15:01:50.613939] I [dht-shared.c:311:dht_init_regex] 0-public_uploads-dht: using regex rsync-hash-regex = ^\.(.+)\.[^.]+$
[2014-06-19 15:01:50.616107] I [socket.c:3561:socket_init] 0-public_uploads-client-0: SSL support is NOT enabled
[2014-06-19 15:01:50.616128] I [socket.c:3576:socket_init] 0-public_uploads-client-0: using system polling thread
[2014-06-19 15:01:50.616158] I [client.c:2273:notify] 0-public_uploads-client-0: parent translators are ready, attempting connect on transport
Final graph:
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  1: volume public_uploads-client-0
  2:     type protocol/client
  3:     option remote-host koraga.int.example.com
  4:     option remote-subvolume /var/lib/glusterfs/brick01/public_uploads
  5:     option transport-type socket
  6:     option username 51275c7d-33b4-46cc-b8e9-9c06b5dfcda5
  7:     option password 36401ce2-18e7-427e-b126-30d2d9351480
  8:     option transport.socket.ssl-enabled off
  9: end-volume
 10:
 11: volume public_uploads-dht
 12:     type cluster/distribute
 13:     subvolumes public_uploads-client-0
 14: end-volume
 15:
 16: volume public_uploads-write-behind
 17:     type performance/write-behind
 18:     subvolumes public_uploads-dht
 19: end-volume
 20:
 21: volume public_uploads-read-ahead
 22:     type performance/read-ahead
 23:     subvolumes public_uploads-write-behind
 24: end-volume
 25:
 26: volume public_uploads-io-cache
 27:     type performance/io-cache
 28:     subvolumes public_uploads-read-ahead
 29: end-volume
 30:
 31: volume public_uploads-quick-read
 32:     type performance/quick-read
 33:     subvolumes public_uploads-io-cache
 34: end-volume
 35:
 36: volume public_uploads-open-behind
 37:     type performance/open-behind
 38:     subvolumes public_uploads-quick-read
 39: end-volume
 40:
 41: volume public_uploads-md-cache
 42:     type performance/md-cache
 43:     subvolumes public_uploads-open-behind
 44: end-volume
 45:
 46: volume public_uploads
 47:     type debug/io-stats
 48:     option latency-measurement off
 49:     option count-fop-hits off
 50:     subvolumes public_uploads-md-cache
 51: end-volume
 52:
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[2014-06-19 15:01:50.619723] E [client-handshake.c:1742:client_query_portmap_cbk] 0-public_uploads-client-0: failed to get the port number for remote subvolume. Please run 'gluster volume status' on server to see if brick process is running.
[2014-06-19 15:01:50.619795] I [client.c:2208:client_rpc_notify] 0-public_uploads-client-0: disconnected from 192.168.134.227:24007. Client process will keep trying to connect to glusterd until brick's port is available
[2014-06-19 15:01:50.629922] I [fuse-bridge.c:4946:fuse_graph_setup] 0-fuse: switched to graph 0
[2014-06-19 15:01:50.630166] I [fuse-bridge.c:3883:fuse_init] 0-glusterfs-fuse: FUSE inited with protocol versions: glusterfs 7.22 kernel 7.22
[2014-06-19 15:01:50.630473] W [fuse-bridge.c:739:fuse_attr_cbk] 0-glusterfs-fuse: 2: LOOKUP() / => -1 (Transport endpoint is not connected)
[2014-06-19 15:01:50.642752] I [fuse-bridge.c:4787:fuse_thread_proc] 0-fuse: unmounting /var/www/shared/public/uploads
[2014-06-19 15:01:50.643121] W [glusterfsd.c:1095:cleanup_and_exit] (-->/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7f6d5111c3fd] (-->/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x7e9a) [0x7f6d513efe9a] (-->/usr/sbin/glusterfs(glusterfs_sigwaiter+0xc5) [0x7f6d51ee91b5]))) 0-: received signum (15), shutting down
[2014-06-19 15:01:50.643144] I [fuse-bridge.c:5444:fini] 0-fuse: Unmounting '/var/www/shared/public/uploads'.
```

of which I think this is the important line:

```
[2014-06-19 15:01:50.619723] E [client-handshake.c:1742:client_query_portmap_cbk] 0-public_uploads-client-0: failed to get the port number for remote subvolume. Please run 'gluster volume status' on server to see if brick process is running.
```

If I manually run service mount_public_uploads start, it mounts just fine. Maybe it's trying to mount before glusterfs is ready?

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a known issue which according to [README.Ubuntu](https://github.com/gluster/glusterfs/blob/f54e9ca3897177ee41b5f5299b94b719448c46cd/extras/Ubuntu/README.Ubuntu) should be fixed in Ubuntu 14.04.

A possible workaround for earlier Ubuntu versions could be to defer the volume mount with a custom upstart job after the GlusterFS server gets started.

Comment: What happened to our long discussion thread here? And how do you defer the volume mount? As I show in the question, I tried that unsuccessfully.

Comment: It was moved to a chat room [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15220/discussion-between-giedrius-rekasius-and-j-pablo-fernandez). I suggest we discuss it there and once the issue is solved update question/answer with relevant details so that it's easy for other people to follow.

Comment: It seems in Ubuntu 14.04 it doesn't work either: http://serverfault.com/questions/611462/glusterfs-failing-to-mount-at-boot-with-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Seems that GlusterFS job is waiting for a wrong event. I'll try to run some tests myself and will post an answer if I find a solution.

Comment: Someone posted a potential solution for the wrong-event issue, but the solution doesn't seem to be enough.

Comment: It should wait for both the network to be up and the GlusterFS server to be started. I didn't get a chance to experiment with it yet though.

Comment: Just for the record, I tried this: start on (started glusterfs-server and mounting TYPE=glusterfs) and some variations but I couldn't get it to work yet.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you installed glusterfs-client from Ubuntu's repo's before you setup your PPA?  Therefor, you wouldn't have the up to date version.

Comment: I didn't but on top of that cron-apt keeps my packages updated as well as puppet. I'm running 3.5 glusterfs-client.